# Expresiones regulares en DataTables .search()

Tags: javascript, datatables, regex

Tengo un DataTable en la que estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda en una columna donde se muestran valores numéricos, pero necesito filtrar con operadores como `≤`, `≥`, `=`, `<` y `>`.

Para ello estoy usando los filtros por columna -> https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter y tengo el siguiente código:

```
var fieldNum = '<select class="custom-select">...'
if ( item.hasClass('field-numeric') ){
    field = fieldNum;

    var item    = $(this)
        col     = item.data('column')
    $('.field-numeric').on('keyup change', function(){
        opr = item.find('option:selected').val();
        val = item.find('input[type=text]').val();

        var reg = new RegExp('\b(0|[1-9][0-9]?|'+ val +')\b');
        table
            .column(col)
            .search(reg, true, false)
            .draw();
    })
}
```

En este caso necesito evaluar los registros que sean menor o igual al valor `val` que introduce el usuario, el caso es que no arroja resultado ninguno.

Aquí hay un ejemplo que funciona como se espera -> https://www.regextester.com/?fam=111377

Supongo que estoy pasando mal el valor de la variable `reg`, pero he probado de mil maneras, incluso pasando literalmente (sin `new RegExp`) la expresión.

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia de lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente me estoy perdiendo de algo, he estado probando lo siguiente sin el resultado esperado:

```
var val = $('input[type=text]').val()
    x   = 3; // A modo de prueba

if ( val <= x ){
    console.log('<=')
    console.log(RegExp('b(0|[1-9][0-9]?|'+ val +')b').test(x)) // output false
} else {
    console.log('>')
    console.log(RegExp('b(0|[1-9][0-9]?|'+ val +')b').test(x)) // output false
}
```

He probado otras maneras de pasar la expresión regular, pero simplemente no funciona de ninguna.

En la comprobación si `val` es menor o igual que `x` funciona como espero. ¿Por qué entonces `console.log(RegExp('b(0|[1-9][0-9]?|'+ val +')b').test(x))` siempre retorna `flase`?

Gracias de antemano